# Mercurial, waiting for lock held by

Tags: java, mercurial, locking

I'm setting up a buildserver (java) with mercurial, maven, jenkins. After installing and configuring jenkins i'm unable to push to my repository

```
waiting for lock on repository /home/javabuild/main-java-repository held by 'ubuntu:3949'
```

the computer `'ubuntu'` is my testserver in a virtual machine, i'm trying to document everything before using it on my main server (i'm completely new to this).

As I issue the commands over time the value of the ports change. I'm thinking that it has something to do with the jenkins build test not releasing the lock?

Anyone? How can i fix this?

EDIT: This question has been asked before but the answer of deleting the wlock or lock file in the `.hg/store` or `.hg/data` folder doesn't work since there is no such file in those folder in my case.

Comment: Are you looking for the `lock` file on your local or remote repository?

Comment: Neither of them have such file. I checked both.

Comment: I can reproduce this exact error in windows if I create a repo A, and clone it to another repo B, and clone that to another repo C. Then I make a commit in C, and push it to B. Then I make a second commit to C and push it to B while at the same time trying to push from B to A. I see a message like:
"waiting for lock on repository C:\repo\B held by 'user:7752'"

Comment: The mercurial was a school project and is gone now. But i can see how your test would result in a lock.